# Script saying two commands not found when they've been entered

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm writing a bash script as the first part of an assignment. If the number of arguments is two, it's supposed to return the sum; if it's anything but two, it's supposed to return the error message and exit the script.

But even when I enter two commands, it still gives me the error message. Why is that? I wrote something very similar -- subtracting numbers -- a second ago and it worked fine.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# This script reads two integers a, b and 
# calculates the sum of them 
# script name: add.sh 

read -p "Enter two values:" a b

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then 
  echo "Pass me two arguments!"
else 
  echo "$a+$b=$(($a+$b))"
fi
```

Comment: you need differentiate between `two arguments of the script` and `reading two values from the standard input`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` reads from standard input, while the arguments (`$1`, `$2`, ...) whose count you are checking with `$#` are command line arguments that can be passed to your program when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
read -p "Enter two values: " a b additional_garbage
if [[ -z $b ]]; then # only have to test $b to ensure we have 2 values
```

The "additional_garbage" is to guard against the funny user who enters **more than 2 values**, and then $b is something like "2 3 4" and your arithmetic is broken.

And to guard against invalid octal numbers (for example if the user enters `08` and `09`), enforce base-10

```
echo "$a+$b=$(( 10#$a + 10#$b ))"
```